# How to skip first N rows and last N rows while reading csv in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a rest api response which returns data in csv. Below is the snapshot of the csv :

```
----BEGIN_HEADER
----END_HEADER



----BEGIN_BODY
"ID", "Name", "Age", "Salary"
1,John,26,20k
2,Michel,28,30k
3,Prashad,27,30k

----END_BODY
----BEGIN_FOOTER
"Status Message"
"COMPLETE"
----END_FOOTER
```

After I read the file in Spark-scala, I need to have only the BODY :

```
"ID", "Name", "Age", "Salary"
1,John,26,20k
2,Michel,28,30k
3,Prashad,27,30k
```

So I tried reading this file in spark but looks like I need to clean the header lines and footer line first then go for spark read. Any other alternative?

Comment: You can define a schema and use `DROPMALFORMED` mode when reading the file.

Comment: Thanks @mazaneicha, the schema is in header so while reading the file I won't be having any schema.